# How to increase the amount of lines written to a file in python

Tags: python, file, stdout

So I have a a program that writes the output of a program to a text file, but it doesn't write out all the lines that are being printed out to the text file. Is there some way to increase this? Here is a code example:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('thefile.txt', 'w')
#Lots of printing here, but not all is written to the text file.
```

Is there a way to increase this limit? Or no?
EDIT: Nevermind, I just found out the problem, I was accidentally ending the program too early.

Comment: Uh, why are you doing this?

Comment: @metatoaster - Redirection of standard out like is fairly common practice - useful for capturing the debugging statements a program might attempt to display.  Especially useful if the program is a windowed program and `sys.stdout` refers to a null file handle.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I know why, but generally this is not the first thing to do for a typical script and I just want the OP to be sure this is the exact use case and not because he wants to use `print` to write to files.

Comment: What evidense do you have that not all the data is written? Are you waiting until the program exits? Have you verified that the print statements are actually executing? Could this be as simple as uou checking before the file cache has been synced to disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely missing doing the same thing for `sys.stderr`. However, you shouldn't be doing that. If you want stdout and stderr to go to a file the just call your program like

```
python prog.py >thefile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: It's often preferable for a program or script to be self-contained, rather than relying on an additional shell script. The feature used here is also a normal and commonly used one well documented for Python.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely likely that you're seeing output that's going to `sys.stderr` as well as `sys.stdout`.  To test, you can use the same file handle in both places:

```
fh = open('thefile.txt', 'w')
stdout_, stderr_ = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = fh
# the code you're importing or printing from
# to restore the defaults.
sys.stdout = stdout_
sys.stderr = stderr_
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to redirecting the standard error output, don't forget to close the file properly after writing to it. If you don't, the output may not be properly synced and the end of the file might be missing. Python's `with` construct is perfect for these cases :

```
with open('thefile.txt', 'w') as f:
    # do the magic here
    pass
```